# Why does your confirmation patron saint have to be the same sex as yourself?

Tags: catholicism, confirmation, patron-saints

I was putting together a confirmation class for this week and was a little surprised to learn that your confirmation saint has to be the same sex as yourself. At least that's what the [religious hippie says](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_v04xKawMas&t=117s)  What is the reason for that? And is that something from canon law or just tradition?

Comment: Don’t you know that there ain’t no sex distinction amongst them that get to heaven?

Comment: Hmm. I tried to look it up and haven't found the mention of confirmation saints/names in either Catechism of Catholic Church nor Canon Law. But as far as I can know, what patron saints can be chosen is always a diocese/parish level tradition. Some parishes would allow any patron saint, some would only allow taking matching sex (since this is the name you take for yourself too) and some oblige confirmation candidates to choose a patron with the same name as your baptism name.

Comment: @User14 not really true. Whether souls have sex is a debated point, but bodies definitely do and you do not cease to be male or female at the resurrection of the bodies.

Comment: @eques where are “the saints” alleged  to be now? That’s the op reference point

Comment: In baptism it would usually be expected that the name given is of a saint or Biblical figure of the same sex as the child. You wouldn't call a boy Margaret, for example. But whether that is rule or custom, I don't know. A similar expectation might exist in taking a confirmation name.

Comment: @User14 Heaven? But that's effectively irrelevant. You claimed the saints don't have a distinction of sex, but that's not really unambiguously true.

Comment: @davidlol That may not be entirely truth when it comes to Our Blessed Mother.  My confirmation patron is St. Alphonsus _Marie_ Ligouri.

Comment: Did you go through the sources listed in The Religious Hippie's video description?

Comment: @jar yeah, I'm using 'em for class today - they were just worksheets

Comment: @PeterTurner I think you misheard her. It sounds to me like she says "if you are a female, you can choose a male patron saint," not "can't" Which is what I always thought the rule was. I watched it with subtitles, and the word used is definitely "can"

Comment: @jaredad7 ohh man, you are totally right - in context that makes a lot more sense.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question was based on a false premise and wouldn't be remotely useful to anyone else since it is not true!